# How can I put the biggest proportion of a horizontal bar chart to the top and not at the bottom as it is the case now?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I make some data analysis. I created some horizontal bar charts and unfortunately the biggest proportion is at the bottom. Do you know how to turn it at the top?

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
professional_uk = pd.read_csv('data/survey_results_public.csv', index_col='Respondent')
schema_df = pd.read_csv('data/survey_results_schema.csv', index_col='Column')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 85)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 85)
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight") 

x = professional_uk['OpSys'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100

x.plot.barh()
plt.xlabel('Percentage')
plt.ylabel('Operating System')
```

Comment: [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) has an `ascending` parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.